# The use of the definite article before nouns when talking about things in general

Tags: articles, definite-article

Tell me please if there is any difference in meaning between the following sentences.

> In America **the** food is delicius and caloric.
>
> In America food is delicious and caloric.

In the first sentence, I am not talking about a specific food, but food that is made in the US in general. Is the article optional in the sentence? If it is not, then what does it add to the meaning?

Comment: Pretty much equivalent. Articles are some of the oldest words in the language (at least 1000 years old). That's a long time to develop idiomatic usages for which we have long lost any explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Food" is a mass noun. Without an article, it could mean all the food in the world, or it could mean any quantity of food, eg:

> I haven't had any food today.
>
> Humans need food.
>
> There is a food shortage.

You need a definite article when you are referring to *specific* food. In your example, it is only the food in America that you want to refer to. It is essentially the same as saying "*American food*".

You *could* say "Food is good in America", but that doesn't specifically mean American food.

Consider this example:

> Cold drinks taste good in hot weather.

This is a generalisation about *all* cold drinks, but the statement is really about the *conditions you drink it in*, not the drink itself, because you could drink the *same* drink in cold weather and make a different statement about it. The same is true if you say "food is good in America". It is like saying *any* food is good *if you eat it in America*. If you buy some food in Mexico and take it accross the border to eat it in America, it doesn't change the properties of the food. So, to be clear that you specifically mean the food that is in America, you need the article.

Comment: I definitely heard natives English speakers dropped "the" in similar context. For example "Food in the restaurant was delicious" not "the food in... What if I just say "Food in America is delicious" what could that mean? Could that mean that some food is delicious?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope I've added a bit more detail, hope that explains it.